# (MetaMask) Changing the default gas

Tags: metamask

I looked for a while on Google/here for if there's a way to manually set the default transaction gas fees, but couldn't find anything. Anyone know if this is possible in metamask? Basically I need super fast transactions all the time for time-sensative swapping on uniswap, so I want to set it to something like 160 gwei & 60000 gas limit so that I don't need to change the gas manually for every transaction. Anyone know if this is possible in metamask? If not, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using remix to trigger transactions?

Comment: @EmrahSarıboz I just mean through the uniswap interface, if you think it'll be better to use remix I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In metamask settings, advanced you can see this option that allows you to set up advanced gas settings at the time of sending of transaction. I don't think there is a way to have it be default at all times.

[image: Metamask settings]

Comment: Yeah, got that on already, thanks for commenting.